# Ghost process on a UDP port - Address already in use (errno=98)

Tags: openvpn, process, port

An OpenVPN server instance loops its initiating sequence in a deadlock.
The log reads:

```
[...] ovpn-server[2311]: TCP/UDP: Socket bind failed on local address [AF_INET][undef]:<port>: Address already in use (errno=98)
```

Booting fails shortly.

Now, `sudo lsof -i:<port>` gives no output.

However, `sudo netstat -tunlp |grep <port>` gives

```
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:<port>           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp6       0      0 :::<port>                :::*                                -
```

The VPN was working one minute then suddenly it failed on me.

To no effect, I tried restarting the systemd service and the operating system (up to date Raspbian OS).

So while similar questions exist, the issue is finding what is taking up the port. It looks like a ghost to me.

How can I free up a port when apparently no process is listening on it?

FYI, the whole deadlock loop from the OpenVPN log:

```
Aug 11 22:53:54 blacked ovpn-server[3188]: TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Aug 11 22:53:54 blacked ovpn-server[3188]: TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Aug 11 22:53:54 blacked ovpn-server[3188]: /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Aug 11 22:53:54 blacked ovpn-server[3188]: /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 10.8.0.1/24 broadcast 10.8.0.255
Aug 11 22:53:54 blacked ovpn-server[3188]: Could not determine IPv4/IPv6 protocol. Using AF_INET
Aug 11 22:53:54 blacked ovpn-server[3188]: Socket Buffers: R=[180224->180224] S=[180224->180224]
Aug 11 22:53:54 blacked ovpn-server[3188]: TCP/UDP: Socket bind failed on local address [AF_INET][undef]:<port>: Address already in use (errno=98)
Aug 11 22:53:54 blacked ovpn-server[3188]: Exiting due to fatal error
Aug 11 22:53:54 blacked ovpn-server[3188]: Closing TUN/TAP interface
Aug 11 22:53:54 blacked ovpn-server[3188]: /sbin/ip addr del dev tun0 10.8.0.1/24
```

The contents of OpenVPN's `server.conf`

```
dev tun
proto udp
port <port>
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/issued/blacked_81f92bec-35b4-4b4a-93a9-3cec80a0019c.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/private/blacked_81f92bec-35b4-4b4a-93a9-3cec80a0019c.key
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push <redacted>
push <redacted>
#Override the Client default gateway by using 0.0.0.0/1 and
# 128.0.0.0/1 rather than 0.0.0.0/0. This has the benefit of
# overriding but not wiping out the original default gateway.
#push "redirect-gateway def1"
client-to-client
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
keepalive 15 120
remote-cert-tls client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-crypt /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ta.key
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
user openvpn
group openvpn
persist-key
persist-tun
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/crl.pem
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log 20
status-version 3
syslog
verb 3
#DuplicateCNs allow access control on a less-granular, per user basis.
#Remove # if you will manage access by user instead of device. 
#duplicate-cn
# Generated for use by PiVPN.io
```

**Update:**

Looking back at the logs, the issue started at the time of a power outage. When the electricity came back on, the OpenVPN server could not recover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using the repair option of the installation script followed by a reboot.

`curl -L https://install.pivpn.io | bash`

(The repair option reinstalls the OpenVPN server with the existing config.)

**UPDATE:**
Turns out I had WireGuard on the box listening on the same port.
WireGuard had no associated process, its a kernel module.
(Possibly it had an associated systemd service but I never checked before I purged it.)

Why `lsof` and `netstat` didn't point out to WireGuard remains a mystery to me.